# MVC 3 How to disable model property validation for float type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I disable the built-in validation for a property of float type?

We have our own custom validation attributes that work fine.
But we have this scenario where we want a float property to accept ( .1 ) as a valid float number. Which obviously means ( 0.1 ), but this number is not accepted by the built-in validation.

Basically I want to disable validation on property-by-property bases and still enforce my own custom validations.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nullable type in your viewmodel property e.g:

`float? MyProp  {get; set;}`

This stops the built in validation from occurring but will still use your custom validation.  Obviously as you have now made the property nullable, you may want to put a Required validation attribute on the property to ensure you get a value.

Comment: Yes, this addresses required field validation, not numeric field validation.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `.3` is actually accepted by the default model binder.  The problem is actually with the client validation implementation.  If client validation isn't important to you, you can solve this problem by opening the web.config and changing `ClientValidationEnabled` to `false` within `AppSettings`.

Comment: As a matter of fact client validation is important to me.

Comment: I tried to disable client validation on that particular field, and guess what? I got server-side validation of that non-localized validation message. ISN'T there a way to disable meta data based validations on primitive types? There ought to be a way...

Comment: "I got server-side validation of that non-localized validation message."

So with client validation off, `.3` still isn't working for you?